# Allowing User input to change function parameters C++

Tags: c++

I just began learning C++ this week, and I'm at a very basic learning stage.

I'm using a switch and attempting to let the user input the parameters of the function `getDayOfWeek`, and then call it to have it carry out the function based on the entered parameters. Any help? Below I have tried `cin >> getDayofWeek()` but truthfully I have no clue!

Thanks!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum){
    string dayName;


    switch(dayNum){
            case 0:
        dayName = "Sunday";
        break;
            case 1:
        dayName = "Monday";
        break;
            case 2:
        dayName = "Tuesday";
        break;
            case 3:
        dayName = "Wednesday";
        break;
            case 4:
        dayName = "Thursday";
        break;
            case 5:
        dayName = "Friday";
        break;
            case 6:
        dayName = "Saturday";
        break;

            default:
                dayName = "invalid day number";
    }

    return dayName;
}


int main()
{

    cin >> getDayOfWeek();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about saving the value entered by the user in a variable `int day` and pass it to `getDayOfWeek(day)`?

Comment: Also, it would be much cleaner with a simple array of strings

Comment: Just a note about the intendation in your `switch`: conditions that need to be matched for a statement to be executed should receive a smaller intendation than the statement itself and `case`s of the same `switch` should receive the same intendation. In this case all cases (including default) violate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to read the input into a variable:

```
int day;

cin >> day;
```

And now, you have a very convenient variable that you can pass to your function:

```
cout << getDayOfWeek(day);
```

Comment: Thanks very much to you and the others who commented, I understand where i went wrong now!

Comment: @quack if this worked for you, tick it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array holding the day names instead of switching over the input, and the `cin >>` needs a variable. Currently you are putting the user input into the variable returned by the function !

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum) {
    string weekdays [7] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    if (dayNum < 0 || dayNum > 6) {
        return string("invalid day number");
    } else {
        return weekdays[dayNum];
    }
}


int main() {
    int dayNum;
    cin >> dayNum;
    weekday = getDayOfWeek(dayNum);
    return 0;
}
```